# Как лучше реализовать масштабируемую таблицу?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Нужна таблица, по размеру типа таблицы Менделеева с текстом и заливкой цветом ячеек. 
Должны быть возможности:

- плавно уменьшать вплоть до размещения по размеру экрана;
- плавно увеличивать вплоть до одной ячейки на всем экране;
- плавно двигать вверх-вниз и вправо-влево в том случае если она не помещается на экране целиком;
- заливки каждой ячейки цветом (программно);

Подскажите ОБЩЕЕ НАПРАВЛЕНИЕ наиболее грамотного решения такой задачи. Куда смотреть? Drawable?

Comment: кастомный `ViewGroup`

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось все задуманное реализовать через `onDraw`. Всю таблицу изначально забиваю в `picture`. Главное везде отключить аппаратное ускорение `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` (иначе может не сработать на реальном устройстве). Масштабирование и скроллинг реализовал через `MyScaleGestureListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` и `MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`.